How to remove all notifications using Accessibility?
The task is to remove all notifications that the application creates using Accessibility.
The app runs in the background and generates a notification
Notification notification = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Service is running")
            .setContentText("App is performing background tasks")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_icon)
            .build();
}

startForeground(1, notification);

`
I'm trying to delete all notifications, the logs show me that the notifications have been deleted, but the notification that the background process creates continues to appear on the phone
`
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();

    if (nodeInfo != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: найдено окно");
        Log.i(TAG,"ForeGround Accessibility");

        
        performActionOnPermissionDialog(nodeInfo);

        
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Удаляем уведомления, так как изменилось состояние окна");
            removeNotifications();
        }
    }
}

private void removeNotifications() {
        
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
           
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
            Log.i(TAG, "Уведомление с ID 1 удалено");
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Не удалось получить NotificationManager");
        }
    }

